# How to enable source-based policy routing with pfsense

Tags: routing, pfsense, policy-routing

I'm trying to setup pfsense to use WAN1 for all LAN traffic except when a computer has been added to an alias I labeled "PRIORITY".  Those computers use WAN2.

On the firewall rules, I set a LAN rule so that:

- "*" source and "! PRIORITY" destination use "WAN1" gateway.
- "! PRIORITY" source and "*" destination use "WAN1" gateway.
- "*" source and "PRIORITY" destination use "WAN2" gateway.
- "PRIORITY" source and "*" destination use "WAN2" gateway.

I think I'm not understanding something since no matter what I do it's WAN1 for everybody or WAN2 for everybody.  My PRIORITY alias seems to have no effect.